# Parse an environment variable in a Windows BAT script

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I'm trying to create a simple application launcher for the software Nuke that puts the path together by evaluating an environment variable.  The value of the variable is used in two ways.  First it's used as-is.  The second time I need to split the variable and use the first half.

The env variable set for the system:

> NUKE_VERSION = 10.0v5

The path to the application:

> C:\Program Files\Nuke10.0v5\Nuke10.0.exe

The code below works fine on the cmd prompt:

```
FOR /F "delims=v tokens=1" %i IN ("%NUKE_VERSION%") DO set NUKE_MAJOR=%i
"C:\Program Files\Nuke%NUKE_VERSION%\Nuke%NUKE_MAJOR%.exe"
```

But when I run a .bat with the code, it returns this error:

> NUKE_VERSIONi was unexpected at this time.

Any insights into what is going on?  I could just do this in python, but something this simple I shouldn't have to, right?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your bat file look like? When you run a bat file, it usually starts its own command environment, that may or may no have the variable declared beforehand, so, there are several factors that may cause this error

Comment: In a Batch file the percent signs of the `for` replaceable parameters must be doubled. Change all `%i` by `%%i`

Comment: If you read the help for the `FOR` command, the eigth line says: **To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a CMD Window a FOR-LOOP uses a single % sign as you have listed in your question.

In a Batch file a FOR-LOOP uses a double %% sign.

FOR /F "delims=v tokens=1" %%i IN ("%NUKE_VERSION%") DO set NUKE_MAJOR=%%i